In Microsoft Entra (formerly Azure Active Directory) how do I add more claims to the openid-configurations manifest claims-supported json
I know there is already a similar question here: How to add more claims to openid-configuration's claims_supported? but it was never answered and my question is specifically about Entra (Azure AD) while that one was not specific to that platform.
Right now when I reach out to https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myAppId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
I get the following options in my json
    "claims_supported": [
        "sub",
        "iss",
        "cloud_instance_name",
        "cloud_instance_host_name",
        "cloud_graph_host_name",
        "msgraph_host",
        "aud",
        "exp",
        "iat",
        "auth_time",
        "acr",
        "nonce",
        "preferred_username",
        "name",
        "tid",
        "ver",
        "at_hash",
        "c_hash",
        "email"
    ],

The consuming system will only allow me to use claims from that node for the username, and we have a custom claim called employeeId that we'd like to use, but it is not in this list and is not available for use.
Is there any way to add a custom claim to the claims_supported options?

You can assign the custom claim to the application by using policy like below:
Connect-AzureAD

$claimsMappingPolicy = [ordered]@{
"ClaimsMappingPolicy" = [ordered]@{
"Version" = 1
"IncludeBasicClaimSet" = $true
"ClaimsSchema" = @(
[ordered]@{
"Source" = "user"
"ID" = "employeeid"
"JwtClaimType" = "employeeid"
}
)
}
}

$appID = "AppID" 
$policyName = "Add employeeid to JWT claims"

$sp = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "servicePrincipalNames/any(n: n eq '$appID')"

$existingPolicies = Get-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId `
| Where-Object { $_.Type -eq "ClaimsMappingPolicy" }
if ($existingPolicies) {
$existingPolicies | Remove-AzureADPolicy
}

$policyDefinition = $claimsMappingPolicy | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 -Compress
$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy" -DisplayName $policyName -Definition $policyDefinition

Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy -Id $sp.ObjectId -RefObjectId $policy.Id


Created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted API permissions:

Updated Manifest  by setting below values:
"acceptMappedClaims": true
AND
"requestedAccessTokenVersion": 2

Generated access token:
GET 
 https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

grant_type: authorization_code 
client_id : ClientId
client_secret : Secret
scope : api://ClientID/claims.read
code : code
redirect_uri : RedirectUrl


The custom claim is displayed:

You can assign the custom claim to the application and make use of the claim based on your requirement.

Where does the api/permission "claims.read" come from?

In Azure Ad application you have to expose an api and add scope

Then in Api permission blade. Add a permission select api in my organisation and search the application name and add the permission

If you want claims in access token then you have to pasa the scope as shown above

I have tried the above answer and I am able to get the token, but it still doesn't show the claim in the claims_supported node of https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myAppId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

https://login.microsoftonline.com/{myAppId}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration it is by default and we cant include the claim there. We can do it via Policy and use it in the application as shown in the answer

Unfortunately that's what this whole question is about. Specifically adding items to that json. The consuming system we are using will only allow us to use claims that in claims_supported I will probably need to see if Microsoft can support that use-case in the future, or the vendor system can relax constraints.

Sure let me know:)

Any update on the issue?

Based on what I have been able to get from Microsoft this is not possible.

Yes as I said it's not possible. Please accept the answer if helpful
